# Updating arrays in react component state

Tags: reactjs, state

In the function below, I am trying to update the state of a react component; the animalMix item is an array. I take a copy, update it and then try to overwrite the original. I have checked that the new array (newAnimalsHeld) is updated correctly, but this is not reflected when i set animalMix in state equal to it.

The whole thing can be seen in context here:
https://codepen.io/timsig/pen/XVdbdo?editors=0010

Many thanks for any help.

```
removePair(){
  console.log('Match!');
  console.log(this.flipped);

  let animalsHeld = [...this.state.animalMix];
  let theMatch = this.flipped[0].props.animal;

  let newAnimalsHeld = animalsHeld.map(function(animal){
    if (animal.animal === theMatch) {
      console.log('MATCH! Animal: ' + animal.animal + 'Match:' + theMatch);
      return {};
    }else{
      return animal;
    }
  });

  console.log('New Animals held: ', newAnimalsHeld);
  this.setState({
    animalMix: newAnimalsHeld,
    doTurn: true
   });

  this.flipped = [];
  console.log(this.state.doTurn, this.state.animalMix);
}
```

Comment: setState is asynchronous, so it might not have updated when you get to that console.log statement: https://github.com/vasanthk/react-bits/blob/master/patterns/19.async-nature-of-setState.md edit: better link

Comment: And I would add that you should use `filter` instead of `map` so you return only animals that do not match instead of also returning empty objects.

Comment: @Timbo What happens to the matched animals? Should they disappear/remove? or they should simply remain flipped?

Comment: Thanks all - it was the asynchronous bit that was throwing me. @Tuna, the matched animals should disappear - it looks confusing at the moment, as i am keeping the cards face up to make developing easier. In the actual game they will be face down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setState is an asynchronous function. However, you can print to console after state has updated in the following manner:

```
this.setState({
    animalMix: newAnimalsHeld,
    doTurn: true
 },() => {console.log(this.state.doTurn, this.state.animalMix);});
```